# Visual Basic .NET Chart not avaliable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to put a chart in my VB .NET program however it isn't available as an option from the toolkit.

This is the picture of the toolkit, the chart option isn't available:

[image]

I've selected in within the choose option list within the setting for the toolbox so I'm not sure why it's not displaying as the two options are both selected:

[image]

Funny thing is I can create a chart perfectly fine in Visual Studio Express 2010, I'm able to see the option for it in the toolkit. However I've been instructed to create the program in VS 2015 so would prefer to resolve this if possible. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't show under `All Windows Forms`. It should be under `Data` category in `ToolBox` when you are in design-mode.

Comment: Also you can search for it in `ToolBox` by typing `Chart` in the search text box.

Comment: @RezaAghaei : We found out his problem was that the chart control is available since .NET 4.0, while he was targeting .NET 2.0.

Comment: @VisualVincent Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at your second screenshot you'll see that it says `Version: 4.0.0.0` for the selected chart control. In .NET this usually refers to the .NET Framework version used, and thus required, by the class. If you target a framework version lower than this you'll not be able to find the control in the tool box.

It also says .NET 4.0 in the [**`Chart` class documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **.NET Framework**
>   Available since 4.0

**Note:** New items are added to the bottom of the category that you initially right-clicked on/in. So unless you, after that, right-click and choose `Sort Items Alphabetically` they'll be at the very bottom of the category.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've scoured the whole thing, no-where to be seen.

Comment: @user3524586 : Strange. Which version of VS 2015 are you using? And which .NET Framework version are you targeting? Try checking if there's any updates for VS.

Comment: I've just created a new project in VS 2015 and there is the chart option under the data tab which I'm able to create a graph with so maybe there's a problem with my project file? I'm using VS 2015 community, downloaded through my university website.

Comment: The project I'm using is an example project from a company which made the counter I'm trying to interface.  I have to add on a library with all their functions when I create a new project, is this interfering with the toolkit somehow?

Comment: @user3524586 : Well that is strange... The project file shouldn't interfere with the tool box. Try restarting Visual Studio and re-opening the project. Are you targeting .NET 4.0 and WinForms? -- **EDIT:** I don't think your company's libraries should interfere with the other controls, no. After all they're most likely not from the same namespace. -- You should still be able to add the control dynamically though.

Comment: It was targeting .NET 2.0, changing it to 4.0 has fixed it. Thank you so much! I've been thrown in a bit at the deep end with this project so not familiar with VS and everything. Appreciate it a lot, big headache prevented.

Comment: @user3524586 : No problem. If you look at your second screenshot you can see that the `Version` field says `4.0.0.0` which, for most .NET controls, refers to the .NET version they use. The bottom of the [**`Chart` class documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx) says `.NET Framework - Available since 4.0`.

Comment: You don't need to keep your old answer, you can keep it as a note for normal cases which users use correct dll version. +1